# Can't press TouchableOpacity when keyboard is up. I need to double press it. React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am making a comments section for my app with React-Native and building for ios. When the keyboard is up to post a comment I can't immedietley press the TouchableOpacity button that submits the post. I need to first press it to close the keyboard then press again to submit.

```
const CommentCreation = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    
    return (
        <View style={commentCreationStyles.container} >
            <TextInput
                value={props.message}
                ref={ref}
                style={commentCreationStyles.input}
                onChangeText={val => props.setMessage(val)}
                autoFocus={false}
                multiline={true}
                returnKeyType={'next'}
                placeholder={'Enter Your Comment'}
                numberOfLines={5}
                replyBool={props.replyBool}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={commentCreationStyles.submitButton}
                onPress={props.addCommentEnabled ? () => {props.addComment(); Keyboard.dismiss()} : null}
            >
                <Ionicons name="ios-send" size={36} color="#D7D7D7" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
})
```

[image: My app]

I have tried keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" and its variations in conjunction with ScrollView in addition to View and replacing View. I have tried these on all levels of the tree. I'm at a loss, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try putting keyboard.dismiss before the addcomment(), or try making it as a promise which when it's done it will send the addcomment()

Comment: This didn't work. The problem is I still have to double click that submit button. Once to get out of the keyboard and again to actually submit it. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Add keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled' in the first View as

```
<View style={commentCreationStyles.container} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled' >
```

Comment: This didn't work. I believe "keyBoardShouldPersistTaps" only works with "ScrollView" anyway. Which I've tried... Thanks for your help though!